# Система рейтинга Django

Tags: python, django

Всем здравствуйте!

Столкнулся с проблемой, помогите решить

У меня есть посты, и к ним можно добавлять комментарии с рейтингом от 1го до 5
В комментариях все хорошо выводится, но мне нужно вывести средний рейтинг для каждого поста. Уже голову сломал

Вот мои модели:

```
class Post(models.Model):
school_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
country = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='KZ')
city = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
content = models.TextField()
website = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
your_email = models.EmailField(default='')
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Comment(models.Model):
post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
text = models.TextField()
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
score = models.IntegerField(default=0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(5), MinValueValidator(1)])

def __str__(self):
    return self.text

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post_detail', args=[str(self.post.id)])
```

Мне нужно сделать вюьюху и темплейт, пока они такие

Вьюха:

```
def post_list(request):
posts = Post.objects.all()
return render(request, 'post_list.html', {'posts': posts})
```

Тепмлейт:

```
                  <a class="nav-link px-2 text-muted" href="{% url 'posts:post_detail' post.id %}">
                <h2>{{ post.school_name }}</h2>
                <p>Автор: {{ post.author }}</p>
                <p>Опубликовано: {{ post.created_at }}</p>
                <p>Обновлено: {{ post.updated_at }}</p>
                <a href="{% url 'posts:post_edit' post.id %}">Редактировать</a>
                <a href="{% url 'posts:post_delete' post.id %}">Удалить</a>
              </a>
```

Comment: Рейтинг назначается комментарию, а не посту. Если к посту можно добавить больше одного комментария, то к рейтингу самого поста это не будет иметь отношения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посчитать общее количество комментариев и посчитать среднее арифметическое.

```
post_list(request):
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=request.post)
    number_comments = len(comments)
    sum_score = 0
    for comment in comments:
        sum_score += comment.score
    rate_post = sum_score / number_comments
    return render(request, 'post_list.html', {'posts': posts, 'rate_post': rate_post})
```

Если нужно рейтинг именно поста, то нужно добавить рейтинг в модель поста, а не комментария. Или можно сделать так чтобы с новым комментарием рейтинг не добавлялся, а обновлялся уже имеющийся (если таковой есть). В таком случае нужно сумму комментариев отфильтровать по автору.

Comment: вы считаете общий рейтинг всех комментариев ко всем постам, а необходимо посчитать только комментарии к определенному посту

Comment: и это можно реализовать без добавления рейтинга к модели поста, рейтинг поста выставляется комментатором во время создания комментария.

Comment: я изменил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Я бы попробовал нечто подобное:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    school_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    country = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='KZ')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    content = models.TextField()
    website = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    your_email = models.EmailField(default='')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def rating(self):
        comments = self.comments.all()
        rating = 0
        for i in comments:
             rating = rating + i.score
        return rating/len(comments)
```

Писал по памяти, поэтому могут быть ошибки. В целом идея должна быть понятна.

Answer (score 0):

Решил немного по другому
добавил отображение среднего рейтинга в детальное представление поста
вышло так

```
def post_detail(request, pk):
post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
comments = post.comments.all()
comment = Comment.objects.filter(post=post)
ratings = Rating.objects.filter(post=post).all()
rating = ratings.values_list('rating')
average_rating = ratings.aggregate(Avg('rating'))['rating__avg']
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CommentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        comment = form.save(commit=False)
        comment.post = post
        comment.user = request.user
        comment.save()
        return redirect('posts:post_detail', pk=post.pk)
else:
    form = CommentForm()
return render(request, 'post_detail.html', {'post': post, 'comments': comments, 'form': form, 'ratings': ratings, 'average_rating': average_rating, 'rating': rating})
```

Comment: как то сложно... в моем варианте в шаблон передаем только post а рейтинг выводим обращаясь к методу post.rating